# Vaadin 8 Checkbox Group select() doesn't work for array

Tags: java, checkbox, vaadin

I have the code that creates a `CheckBoxGroup` (based on Vaadin 8 Sampler):

```
public void setPossibleAnswers(List <String> answerOptions) {       
   answerCheckBoxes = new CheckBoxGroup<>("", answersOptions);      
}
```

I'm using this method to select given items in a group:

```
public void setAnswer(String answer) {
    String[] answers = answer.split(",");
    answerCheckBoxes.select(answers);
}
```

But this code selects only the first element of the array. What I need is to select all elements. Does any body know where is my mistake?

Comment: Are `sample` and `answerCheckBoxes` the same thing? Can you show us how it's declared?

Comment: Yes, I've update my question

Comment: You set the container up as integers, but then you want to select strings.  i'm even surprised, that anything is selected at all